# Using log4net to log unhandled errors when using OWIN

Tags: log4net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Can you point me to some log4net tutorial or samples that logs all unhandled exceptions occurring on my MVC Web Api when using OWIN?

I have a `Startup` class that configures `Castle Windsor` and `OAuth` and I'm not sure how application errors are handled for OWIN enabled applications.

I have tried putting the log4net code in the `Application_Error` event in `global.asax` but it never gets executed.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_Start() {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }        
    protected void Application_Error(object sender,EventArgs e) {
        Exception lastException = Server.GetLastError();
        var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WebApiApplication));
        logger.Fatal(lastException);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is?

**EDIT: web.config** with log4net configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net debug="true">
    <logger name="SiteWorksAPI">
      <level value="Debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="C:\ProgramData\Site\SiteWorksAPILog.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="============================================================%nLogger = %logger.%nLocation = %location.%nUnique Token = %property{x-fcc-uniquetoken}.%nDate = %date{dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss}.%nMessage = %message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <applicationName value="SiteWorks.API" />
      <logname value="SiteWorks API Log" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="Date: %date{dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss} %nMessage: %message %nIdentity: %identity %nUnique Token: %property{x-fcc-uniquetoken} %nChange Time Stamp: %property{x-fcc-changedatetime} %nOriginal Time Stamp: %property{x-fcc-originaltimestamp} %nOriginating System: %property{x-fcc-originatingsystem} %nOriginating User: %property{x-fcc-originatingusername} %nRequest Uri: %property{Request} %nResponse Headers: %property{ResponseHeaders}%nLogger: %logger  %nThread: %thread  %n%n%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Is log4net loading the configuration correctly from the web.config file?

Comment: I am not sure as I don't think log4net is being loaded at all.  Even when I try and log something with `log.Debug('Test');` straight after the `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: There are a few things you can do to find out the issue: 1) check `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` to see if log4net is loading the config (which presumably _is_ in the web,config file?) 2) look at the messages in `LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<LogLog>();` for any load errors and 3) enable log4net debug mode in the config with `<lognet debug="true">` at the root

Comment: Enabled `<lognet debug="true">` at the root and `LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<LogLog>();` returned no errors.  Also `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` returned `true`.

Comment: Can you show your log4net config?

Comment: Amended OP and added log4net portion of web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not seeing any log events because you haven't defined a `root` logger in your config - the only logger you've defined is called `SiteWorksAPI` so any loggers you create with any other name - for example, the one named after `typeof(WebApiApplication)` - will not log anything. If you add a breakpoint on the logging statement you'll see that all log levels are disabled.

The appenders defined in a root logger are inherited by all named appenders (unless the child appenders are defined with `additivity = false`) - but child appenders set their own log level.

```
<root>
  <level value="Debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</root>
```

Edit: there's also another thing to consider - your defined logger only uses the EventLogAppender - note that in order to log to the Event Log, the documentation states [EventLogAppender will fail if you try to write using an event source that doesn't exist unless it is running with local administrator privileges](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender.html) but **the event source needs to be created by an elevated process**.

For testing purposes, you might want to add your `FileAppender` to the logger.

Comment: Thanks! Just put in your changes and it now logs fine.